# Which of the following is/are metrics on $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Which of the following is/are metrics on $\Bbb R$

1. $d(x,y) = min (x,y)$
2. $d(x,y) = max (x,y)$
3. $d(x,y) = |x^n - y^n|$ when $n$ is odd number.
4. $d(x,y) = |x^n - y^n|$ when $n$ is even number.

My Attempt:

Since $d(x,y) \geq 0$ for a metric. But $d(1,-1) = min (1,-1) = -1 \ngeq 0$ Hence
option 1 is not a metric on $\Bbb R$

Also $d(-1,-2) = max (-1,-2) = -1 \ngeq 0$ Hence
option 2 is not a metric on $\Bbb R$

Take $n = 2$ then from 4, we get $d(x,y) = |x^2 - y^2|$. Now $d(-1,1) = |(-1)^2 - {1}^2| = |1-1| = 0$
But $-1 \neq 1$ So option 4 is not a metric on $\Bbb R$ for $n$ = even number

In option 3, when we take $n = 1,3$ then $d(x,y) = |x - y|$ and $d(x,y) = |x^3 - y^3|$ becomes metrics on $\Bbb R$

Please help me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Don't forget that you'll also need to demonstrate the triangle inequality,

Comment: So far, you're not wrong anywhere. Your reasoning why 1, 2 and 4 do not define a metric is entirely correct. You're also right that option 3 does in fact define a metric, but you still have to prove it.

Comment: How can prove 3 in general ?

Comment: By checking each of the three properties a metric is supposed to have. Two of these are easy for 3, and the triangle inequality can be reduced to the case $n=1$ (for which you might already know it's a metric).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you have done is correct and to show that for odd $n$ $|x^n - y^n|$ is metric we need to show, $d(x,y) \ge 0$ is trivial

$d(x,y) = 0 \iff x =y $ which is clear as $x^n = y^n$ implies $x=y$ for odd $n$

and also $$ |x^n - z^n| < |x^n - y^n| + |y^n - z^n| $$

follows from triangle inequality